# How to create multiple page in dompdf

Tags: php, mysql, dompdf

I created a dompdf which fetch data from database mysql. But my problem is how i am going to iterate a page if the data of each user will exceed 19 transactions?

```
<?php
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', false );
define( 'DISABLE_WP_CRON', true );
require('wp-load.php'); 

global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

$d = $current_user->user_login;

// include autoloader
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();

$html = '<html><body>'.
        '<p>Date | Details </p>';

$ff = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE dd = '$d' ORDER by tdate");
    foreach ( $ff as $jj ) {
     $html = '<p>'.$jj->tdate.' | '.$jj->details.'</p>';
    }

$html .= ''</body></html>';

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
//$dompdf->stream();

// Output the generated PDF (1 = download and 0 = preview)
$dompdf->stream("codex",array("Attachment"=>0));
```

For now it works fine for 1 page only but my problem is when the data of each user exceeds 19 to higher transactions it will break the page. I want to set 19 transaction per page.

BTW sample output look like this:

[image: Outout]

Can anyone here help me?

Thanks.

Comment: dompdf does the  paging automagically. If u want to force a page break you can do it by the CSS/styling an element with `page-break-before: always;` or `page-break-after: always;`. Hope this helps you

Comment: @PunitGajjar but it does not look like the image i added i guess. Please check i added an output.

Comment: You are giving inline CSS to the elements  right ? ?

Comment: @PunitGajjar no i just added a css external.

Comment: Try inline CSS buddy...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$start = '<html><body>';
$body  = '<p>Date | Details </p>';
$ff = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE dd = '$d' ORDER by tdate");
    foreach ( $ff as $jj ) {
     $body .= '<p>'.$jj->tdate.' | '.$jj->details.'</p>';
    }
$end= '</body></html>';
$dompdf->loadHtml($start.$body.$body.$end);
```

**implement this code in your code.**